# AS3 NetStream lags on first frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, air

I'm developing an application in Adobe Air to display videos for a museum exhibit at a resolution of 2560x1440. The application works without a hitch on my machine, but when I run it on another (less powerful) computer, it does not function as intended. I've texted the application on two machines besides my own.

The problem is when one of the videos is called up, the video is called up and displays the first frame of the video and lags there for a good number of seconds (5-10), however I can still hear audio. After about 8-10 seconds, the video plays back as if it had been playing before and stutters briefly (1-2 seconds) before resuming playback normally. This is consistent behavior every time a video is launched as long as it's a fairly large video (> 50 MB as far as I can tell).

This does not happen on my development machine, which has a GTX 980 graphics card in it, but besides that and the motherboard, I can't think of any differences between the specs of the multiple machines.

The video throws an event indicating the buffer is full immediately as a video is launched, so buffering doesn't seem to be the issue.

Edit: [Code](http://pastebin.com/QRHR7fWd) (Pastebin)

Edit 2: Figured out it was the first frame, not a black screen

Comment: Show your code on how you display the stream.  2560x1440 compressed video would be pretty demanding on the system. Are you getting any other status events from the stream/connection?

Comment: Edited with a pastebin link (for syntax highlighting)

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip,  use `StageVideo` instead of `Video` if you can as it performs much better. Also inline functions can come back to bite you if you're not careful.

Comment: So when you play a video in question,  what NetStatusEvent codes do you get and in what order?

Comment: [Here's a screenshot of my console](http://i.imgur.com/5tbfkqZ.png)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Can you explain what you mean by inline functions? I'd use StageVideo if I were sure it could do the job the way I currently have the setup running, but I don't know how much of my code I'd have to move around or change in order for that to work.

Comment: You create anonymous functions as second parameter to `addEventListener`, which is bad practise in general, because it makes it hard to remove the listener again. With the listener lingering on, so does the object.

Comment: Right - generally that's pretty bad but I don't plan on removing those listeners. I usually handle short listener content with inline functions.

Comment: There was a long time ago, developers were working on usual computers, so we never have to face this kind of issue ;)
Think about the target, the audience you wanna reach ;)
Best regards.
N.

Comment: @tatactic What? The audience is museum goers. I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: @OlinKirkland, try the **`stageVideo`** method, it will give you hardware-powered decoding instead of a **`video`** object which is software-powered. This should help eliminate if graphics cards are the issue on those two other machines...

Comment: I figured it out - I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not entirely sure where the root of the problem lies, but what fixed it was adding this code right after calling the video. What it does is pause the playback and add a timer for one second, then seek 0.5 seconds into the video. I haven't run tests with this yet beyond getting past that first frame lag, but it works.

```
ns.pause();
var hesitate:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
hesitate.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent)
{
    ns.seek(0.5);
    ns.resume();
});
hesitate.start();
```